# What does Error Id means and where it is logged in "Sorry to Interrupt" message in Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

While working on lightning experience, we usually get **"Sorry To Interrupt"** dialog box.

**Error Message:**

> "This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. First,
>   would you give us some details? We're reporting this as error ID:
>   -1983769763".

What does this error ID means? Where is it logged? How do I get details about what exactly happened at backend?

Comment: If you want more details, you need to create a case.

Comment: Can you share the code thats causing this failure ?